# How can I pass captured data between two Rundeck Job References?

Tags: rundeck

I am trying to figure out if it is possible in Rundeck to generate output from one Job Reference, capture it as a global variable, and pass that variable to a second Job Reference.

### Job Reference 1

Step 1 executes a PowerShell script on node WinServer1.  The output is an FQDN (for example, workstation1.yadayada.com).  I have a Key/Value/Data filter that captures this output as hostname.  It is accessible via ${data.hostname*@WinServer1}.

Step 2 creates a Global Variable using the following:
Value:  ${data.hostname*@WinServer1}
Group:  export
Name:  hostname

Step 3 is a test to output.

```
Write-Host "data.hostname = @data.hostname@"
Write-Host "export.hostname = @export.hostname@"
```

The output of these commands are as expected:

> data.hostname =   workstation1.yadayada.com
>   export.hostname =   workstation1.yadayada.com

### Job Reference 2

Step 1, for the purposes of this example, is the same PowerShell code as shown above.  The output is as follows:

> data.hostname =   
>   export.hostname =

---

In Job Reference 2, I would expect for data.hostname to be empty, but I am expecting export.hostname to contain workstation1.yadayada.com as I made it a global variable.  Am I misunderstanding how global variables work in Rundeck?  Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do?  I'm happy to supply any additional information that may be useful in troubleshooting this issue.

**Some Other Things I've Tried**

- I have attempted to pass the export.hostname variable as an argument to Job Reference 2 Step 1, but I had the same results.
- I have attempted to move the Global Variable step into the parent job between the two Job Reference steps, but the ${data.hostname*@WinServer1} is empty by the time that step runs.
- I have attempted to put the exact same Key/Value/Data log filter on the parent job, but it won't even capture the data for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second job needs a option to "receive" the data values generated in the first job though Job Reference Step (you'll pass as argument on the 'Arguments' [textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjKMY.jpg)). I leave an example:

Job One:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>d73f5404-371a-49b6-af7e-7951c2dd859a</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>JobOne</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <description>STEP 1: GENERATE THE DATA VALUE</description>
        <fileExtension>.ps1</fileExtension>
        <plugins>
          <LogFilter type='key-value-data'>
            <config>
              <logData>true</logData>
              <regex>^(THECAR)\s*=\s*(.+)$</regex>
            </config>
          </LogFilter>
        </plugins>
        <script><![CDATA[# generate data
Write-Host "THECAR=bmw"]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>powershell.exe</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
      <command>
        <description>STEP 2: TEST THE DATA VALUE</description>
        <fileExtension>.ps1</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[# print the data values
Write-Host "Testing the data value..."
Write-Host "My car is an @data.THECAR@"]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>powershell.exe</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
      <command>
        <description>STEP 3: CALL THE JOBTWO AND SEND THE DATA VALUE TO JOBTWO OPTION DEFINED</description>
        <jobref name='JobTwo' nodeStep='true'>
          <arg line='-option_for_receive ${data.THECAR}' />
          <uuid>a3191daf-eceb-4162-8f44-c8fe5b620ecc</uuid>
        </jobref>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>d73f5404-371a-49b6-af7e-7951c2dd859a</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

Job Two:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='option_for_receive' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>a3191daf-eceb-4162-8f44-c8fe5b620ecc</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>JobTwo</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.ps1</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[# print the option (that receives data value from JobONE)
Write-Host "The JobONE car is: @option.option_for_receive@"
# all done.]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>powershell.exe</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>a3191daf-eceb-4162-8f44-c8fe5b620ecc</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fklqq.jpg) the result.

Comment: Urgh!  I am so frustrated because I tried passing the data value as an argument multiple times, but I completely left out the step of creating the option to receive the value.  Doh!  **Thanks so much for the help!**

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I found is to use python library json_kvs
https://github.com/mlubkin/json_kvs

you can write vars in first step and read in second
also you can use your jobId as scope for using same json file in multiple jobs