# Rundeck passing key-data value as command line argument

Tags: rundeck

How I can pass the log filter `key-value data` into one of the reference job as an argument.

I was able to use the options available on the job as an argument to pass on the child reference job use,

But when I passed my log filter key-value data variable as `${data.my_log_filer_var}` from the parent job argument, it does not evaluate in the child job but other argument passing is working for like for other option variables, I passed as: `${option.my_another_var}`

Please let me know if there is any other way to pass the `${data.my_log_filer_var}` to my child job.

Answer (score 0):

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61802154/10426011), I made a little example. Basically, you need an option on the child's job to "receive" the argument from the parent's job. This example is a couple of job definitions that you can [import](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/creating-jobs.html#importing-job-definitions) to your instance.

Child job (contains an option, this option is called from parent job passing the data variable):

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 0aeaa0f4-d090-4083-b0a5-2878c5f558d1
  loglevel: INFO
  name: ChildJob
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  options:
  - name: opt1
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: 'echo "the argument is: ${option.opt1}"'
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 0aeaa0f4-d090-4083-b0a5-2878c5f558d1
```

And the Parent job (creates a data value and passes it to a child using arguments `-opt1 ${data.mydata}`)

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 5c3d4248-9761-45d4-b164-6e38d5146007
  loglevel: INFO
  name: ParentJob
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: env
      plugins:
        LogFilter:
        - config:
            invalidKeyPattern: \s|\$|\{|\}|\\
            logData: 'true'
            regex: ^(USER)\s*=\s*(.+)$
          type: key-value-data
    - exec: 'echo "the data value is ${data.USER}, sending to child job using arguments
        on job reference step..."'
    - jobref:
        args: -opt1 ${data.USER}
        group: ''
        name: ChildJob
        nodeStep: 'true'
        uuid: 0aeaa0f4-d090-4083-b0a5-2878c5f558d1
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 5c3d4248-9761-45d4-b164-6e38d5146007
```

Answer (score 0):

The `global variable` **step** can capture data variable captured by `key-value data` **log filter**.

For example, if you capture the key-value data to `export` group, you can create a global variable `{export.keyname*}`, which can be used on other steps or in notifications. Note that if you only want the value from a single node, you should use `{export.keyname@nodename}` instead.

[Rundeck Docs](https://docs.rundeck.com/3.4.0/manual/workflow-steps/builtin.html#global-variable)