# Rundeck Community passing variable/parameter between job

Tags: rundeck

I have job in rundeck inline script where I have defined variable like
Job1:
ABC="xyz"
echo "ABC=$ABC"

Now,I would like to call this job in another job(like job2) and want to print the value of ABC.
How can I catch the value of 'ABC' in another job's inline script?

Answer (score 0):

The easier way is to pass that data value by creating an option on the second job to "receive" the data generated by the first job. That was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61800935/how-can-i-pass-captured-data-between-two-rundeck-job-references/61802154#61802154).